# C++ operators overriding

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-keyword, overriding

can you explain me why this code doesn't work.
operator+ override:

```
Fraction& Fraction::operator+(const Fraction& f) {
    Fraction temp;
    if (this->denominator == f.denominator){
        temp.numerator = this->numerator + f.numerator;
        temp.numerator = this->numerator;
        temp.simplifier();
    }
    else {
        temp.numerator = this->numerator * f.denominator + f.numerator * this->denominator;
        temp.denominator = this->denominator * f.denominator;
        temp.simplifier();
    }
    return temp;
}
```

operator= override:

```
void Fraction::operator=(const Fraction& f) {
    this->numerator = f.numerator;
    this->denominator = f.denominator;
}
```

after code

```
Fraction res;
res = f + g;
```

fields of res stay uninitialised.
But, for example, code

```
Fraction res = g;
```

is working properly. So operator= doesn't understand (f + g) as one object?
Thanks.

Comment: Compiler should warn about this; but with ```Fraction::operator+``` you're returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: Your `operator+` returns a reference to a local variable, which is undefined behavior. `Fraction res = g;` is an initialization, it won't result in a call to `operator=`.

Comment: Fyi one of the best questions and answer-stacks on this site, [**Operator Overloading**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading). It's worth the read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your overload is returning a reference to an object, `temp`, which is destroyed when the function returns.

Accessing that object after the function returns is undefined.

Return by value instead:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction& f)
```

And

```
Fraction res = g;
```

isn't an assignment but an initialisation and will not use your assignment operator.

Comment: Specifically, `Fraction res = g;` will use the copy construction if you have defined one, or a compiler supplied one if you haven't.  (I suspect the compiler supplied one will be fine.)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a reference to a temporary that was created on the stack. "temp", in operator+, has a lifetime that ends when operator+ returns. Its contents will likely be altered in chaotic ways, the next time a method is called.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to return a reference to a temporary, the other problem you have is:

```
    if (this->denominator == f.denominator){
        temp.numerator = this->numerator + f.numerator;
        temp.numerator = this->numerator;  // *HERE*
        temp.simplifier();
    }
```

I am pretty sure the line labelled *HERE* should be:

```
        temp.denominator = this->denominator;
```

Otherwise you will call simplifier with an uninitialized denominator and bad things will happen.

I would also recommend making `operator +` a free standing binary operator which takes two `Fraction` arguments - and make it use `operator +=`.  Note: lhs is passed as a copy, *not* as a const reference.

```
Fraction operator +(Fraction lhs, const Fraction &rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return "temp" as reference then you have to declare "temp" as:

```
static Fraction temp;
```

And now everything will work. Why because appending `static` keyword before declaration made "temp" available until program termination..

Comment: But *don't* do this.  It make everything horribly unthread-safe, and potentially *very* confusing.  Can you convince yourself that `a + b + c` is safe for example?

Comment: Yes I agree with you...Thanks.

Comment: It's not only confusing, it's wrong - `a + b + c + d` will not give the same result as `(a + b) + (c + d)`.